# making bar plot using ggplot2 and matching with data file

Tags: r

I have a CSV data file with 4 columns. below you can see the screen shot of that.

[image]

I am trying to visualize my data and make a bar for each Pos(x axis). I used the following code to do so.

```
p <-ggplot(data, aes(pos, log))
p +geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = group))
```

and got the bar plot but the order of items (positions) at the x axis is not like my data file but they has to be in the same order.

[image]

how can I make a bar plot in which the items on the x axis have the same order as my file?

and here is the screen of dput(data):

[image]

Comment: Instead of the screen shot of your data, can you provide the output of `dput(data)`?

Comment: You can do `data$pos <- factor(data$pos, levels = data$pos)` to make it an ordered factor

Comment: @J.Con: attached.

Comment: Please, don't use print screen while sharing your data. Copy and paste your data so other users can use it

Comment: @user7249622
There is no difference between print screen from excel or from R. Both can't be used easily by users to reproduce your error.

Comment: Copy and paste the `dput(data)` output directly from the console into your question, highlight and press `ctl`+`k`.

Comment: @Patronus: perfect. worked.